# How to remove handles from a node?

Tags: vector, inkscape

simple as that, but i dont find any options!!!

I dont want to preserve image. i just want to remove handles from a node to get sharp corners with no curves.

Click+Ctrl creates handle on node, but there is no option to remove it (Ctrl+Z in that case works but not a real answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the node with the *Edit Paths by Nodes Tool (F2)*.

Click on the *Make Selected Nodes Corner* button in the Tools Control Bar along the top. This will turn it into a corner node. Smooth nodes show as a square, corner nodes show as a diamond shape. Click on it again to remove the handles entirely.

[image]

Note: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicking on a node cycles through different nodes, including corner nodes, but will not remove handles.

Comment: i found out if i hold `ctrl` and click on each handle (no dragging), they get removed individually.

Answer (score 2):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking on the *handle* (not the *node*) will remove the handle, creating a sharp corner.